# Download Blob with React Query, createObjectURL error

Tags: reactjs, download, react-query

Using fetch I can create a download link by doing the following code

```
const result = await fetch(authLinkProps.url, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: getUserToken(),
      },
    });

    const blob = await result.blob();
    const href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

All works fine but I'm using React Query for my project so I want to be consistent and use this to do the same thing.

If I do the following

```
const { data, error } = useDocuments(authLinkProps.url);
let href: string = '';
console.log(data);
if (data !== undefined) {
    href = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
}
```

Where useDocuments is

```
return useQuery<Blob, Error>('document-download', async () => {
    const dwnldHeader = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: currentUser,
        responseType: 'blob',
      },
    };
    const { data } = await axios.get<Blob>(apiUrl, dwnldHeader);
    return data;
  });
```

I get the error

```
"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed."
```

Data looks like a blob if I console it out?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

`useQuery` seems to convert blob responses to Strings. What worked for me was to use arraybuffer return type instead and then convert that to blob.

Furthermore the `responseType` is not part of the headers object, but of the configuration.

In your case for the useDocuments

```
return useQuery<Blob, Error>('document-download', async (apiUrl) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: currentUser,
    },
    responseType: 'blob',
  };
  const { data } = await axios.get(apiUrl, config);
  return new Blob(data);
});
```

Comment: good spot on the reponseType! yeah, I've tried a number of similar things but no matter what I do the file seems to be corrupted when I use Axios... looks like it works until I try and open the file and it fails to load.. works perfectly with fetch

Comment: Simply converting my `responseType` from `stream` to `blob` fixed it for me on Axios. Thanks @Michael Franke